# Tastypie sending POST to update Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, post, tastypie

I've recently got started with Django (and python generally!), and I was looking to use Tastypie in order to automate additions to my database.

For my current problem I have two tables in my database, one which displays the Company Name and Company ID, and the other which holds all the licence key information, as below:

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name= "Company Name")
    company_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name= "Company ID")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name


class Licence(models.Model):
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name= "Company ID")
    licence_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name= "Licence Key")
    lpars = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = "", verbose_name= "List of Systems")
    rss = models.BooleanField(default = None, verbose_name= "RSS")
    gui = models.BooleanField(default = None, verbose_name= "RACFGui")
    exr = models.BooleanField(default = None, verbose_name= "Exception Reporter")
    zdt = models.BooleanField(default = None, verbose_name= "zDetect")
    bg = models.BooleanField(default = None, verbose_name= "BreakGlass")
    sspr = models.BooleanField(default = None, verbose_name= "Self Service Password Reset")
    rss_custom = models.BooleanField(default = None, verbose_name= "RSS Custom")
    expiry = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    trial = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name= "Trial?")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.licence_key
```

I've then defined all of the api stuff here:

**resources.py**

```
class CompanyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Company.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'company'

class LicenceResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Licence.objects.all()
        include_resource_uri = True
        resource_name = 'licence'
        authorization = Authorization()
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['company'] = bundle.obj.company_id
        return bundle
```

This works great when I make GET requests, and displays the information below:

```
{
"bg": false,
"company": "xxxx", (blanked out for security)
"expiry": "2018-05-11",
"exr": true,
"gui": false,
"id": 13,
"licence_key": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
"lpars": "xxxx xxxx",
"resource_uri": "/api/licence/13/",
"rss": true,
"rss_custom": true,
"sspr": false,
"trial": false,
"zdt": true
```

}

**However**, when I try to replicate this with a `POST request`, I get

> "error_message": "NOT NULL constraint failed: licence_licence.company_id_id"

I understand that I haven't submitted this value in with the POST request, but I assumed that the `_id` was the id of that entry of the database, which is usually automatically managed by Django.

Is there a way to have this either managed by Django if omitted, or is there a smarter way to format the POST request?

Many thanks for your time! This is my first post on SO, so if I've omitted anything please let me know :)

Comment: I don't know Tastypie (Django Rest Framework is the usual tool for this kind of thing) but it seems to me you defined a `dehydrate` method to specify how the company field was output, perhaps you need a `hydrate` method to specify the reverse?

Comment: Indeed, see the docs on [hydrate](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#the-hydrate-cycle).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Many thanks! I'll have to check hydrate out - I appreciate the guidance in the meantime :)